# Error when indexing file in solr with oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, apache, solr, apache-tika

I configured my data_config.xml this way:

```
<entity name="bop_anexo" processor="SqlEntityProcessor" query="SELECT ID_BOP_ANEXO,
                        ID_BOP_REFERENCIA,
                        NM_ANEXO,
                        TP_ANEXO,
                        DECODE64_CLOB3(REPLACE(ANEXO, 'data:application/pdf;base64,', '')) as ANEXO_CONVERTIDO,
                        ANEXO,
                        MINIATURA,
                        ID_SITUACAO,
                        DT_MANUTENCAO,
                        ID_USUARIO_MANUTENCAO
                FROM BOP_ANEXO WHERE TP_ANEXO = 'pdf'" transformer="ClobTransformer">
    <field column="ID_BOP_ANEXO" name="id"/>
    <field column="ID_BOP_REFERENCIA" name="id_bop_referencia"/>
    <field column="NM_ANEXO" name="nm_anexo"/>
    <field column="TP_ANEXO" name="tp_anexo"/>
    <field column="ANEXO_CONVERTIDO" name="anexo_convertido" clob="true"/> 
    <field column="ANEXO" name="anexo" clob="true"/> 
    <field column="ID_SITUACAO" name="id_situacao"/>
    <field column="DT_MANUTENCAO" name="dt_manutencao"/>
    <field column="ID_USUARIO_MANUTENCAO" name="id_usuario_manutencao"/>
</entity>
```

But when I try to execute dataimport, this error appears to me:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: TransactionLog doesn't know how to serialize class oracle.sql.CLOB; try implementing ObjectResolver?
at org.apache.solr.update.TransactionLog$1.resolve(TransactionLog.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeVal(JavaBinCodec.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeSolrInputDocument(JavaBinCodec.java:496)
at org.apache.solr.update.TransactionLog.write(TransactionLog.java:361)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.add(UpdateLog.java:429)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.add(UpdateLog.java:415)
```

And when I search on solr query, this result appears to me:

```
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":32,
"params":{
  "q":"*:*",
  "indent":"on",
  "wt":"json",
  "_":"1486041075119"}},
  "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id_bop_referencia":"902",
        "miniatura":"oracle.sql.CLOB@3c0c5a58",
        "tp_anexo":"pdf",
        "anexo":"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKN...",
        "anexo_convertido":"%PDF-1.4\n%âãÏÓ\n4 0 obj\n<</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 45/Length 4609/Height 48/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream\nÿØÿà\u0000\...",
        "id":"971",
        "nm_anexo":"report.pdf",
        "_version_":1557683947554471936},
          {
```

I have a base64_clob file type, and I converted it into the oracle database with an sql query, but solr and tika do not index the correct text, just as I showed it to you. Someone knows what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried it without any conversion in the select statement. Just with the ClobTransformer? Maybe there is double-work happening there.

Comment: Yes, but could not turn into text because the file is in base 64.

Comment: Then try removing the transformer, because you already decoded the CLOB on Oracle layer. Though what you want to do with the file itself is not clear anyway.

Comment: I do that, but appears the same error to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you just need to implement `ObjectResolver` for this type, so Solr will know how to serialize your

> Allows extension of JavaBinCodec to support serialization of arbitrary data types. Implementors of this interface write a method to serialize a given object using an existing JavaBinCodec

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/util/JavaBinCodec.ObjectResolver.html